# Pac-Man - keep pacman moving in a direction once one key is pressed and released

Tags: python, pygame, pacman

So, I want to code pac-man in python3 with the pygame module. However I do not know how to keep pac-man moving once a single key is pressed. The aim is to press for example the "up" key and pac-man will continue to move in that direction until he hits a boundary, even if I release the key. As of right now I have not coded these boundaries as I am prioritising the continuous movement of pac-man. I attempted to nest a while loop which should've worked but that obviously gave me a phat run-time error. Any ideas on how I can do this?

```
if keys[pygame.K_UP] and (pac.y - pac.radius) > 0:
        pac.y -= pac.speed
        pac.direction = "UP"
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and (pac.y + 2*(pac.radius) + pac.speed) < height:
        pac.y += pac.speed
        pac.direction = "DOWN"
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and (pac.x - pac.radius) > 0:
        pac.x -= pac.speed
        pac.direction = "LEFT"
        left = True
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and (pac.x + 2*pac.radius + pac.speed) < width:
        pac.x += pac.speed
        pac.direction = "RIGHT"
        right = True
```

The expected result is to input a single direction and pac man will move in that direction by himself without needing to hold the key down. In reality what happens is I end up having to hold the key down so that pac man will move in the wanted direction.

Comment: Could you please add some more of you code around the if statement.

Comment: You are currently moving pacman (e.g. `pac.x += pac.speed`) only when a key is pressed (e.g. `elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]...`). You should store the direction information when a key is pressed and put the moving code someplace which is periodically executed (e.g. use a timer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving your pacman directly when the key is pressed is not going to work for your program.  You should set pacman's speed or something here and apply that each frame in another function.

```
def update():
    pac.y += pac.yspeed
    pac.x += pac.xspeed


while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and (pac.y - pac.radius) > 0:
        pac.yspeed = 1
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and (pac.y + 2*(pac.radius) + pac.speed) < height:
        pac.yspeed = -1
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and (pac.x - pac.radius) > 0:
        pac.xspeed = -1
        left = True
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and (pac.x + 2*pac.radius + pac.speed) < width:
        pac.xspeed = 1
        right = True
    if keys[pygame.K_ESC]:
        break
    update()
    # Do all your other stuff
```

Comment: Exactly. But since you've gone this far, the answer would be complete if it showed how to call `update` in each time step.

Comment: This worked really nicely, I had to make some minor adjustments to ensure that pac-man only moved in the x direction or the y direction at a time so I used some if statements. But this was absolutely perfect, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating an object within your Pac-Man class that keeps track of the direction Pac-Man should be moving (basically your `pac.direction` you're already setting). For each movement iteration, instead of checking your keys map, instead check `pac.direction` and perform the operation it says. Basically have it look similar to this if you want to keep your code mostly the way it is:

```
if pac.direction == "UP" and (pac.y - pac.radius) > 0:
        pac.y -= pac.speed
elif pac.direction == "DOWN" and (pac.y + 2*(pac.radius) + pac.speed) < height:
        pac.y += pac.speed
elif pac.direction == "LEFT" and (pac.x - pac.radius) > 0:
        pac.x -= pac.speed
        left = True
elif pac.direction == "RIGHT" and (pac.x + 2*pac.radius + pac.speed) < width:
        pac.x += pac.speed
        right = True
```

Then you just need to set `pac.direction` to the correct value when a key is pressed before you get to the code. I must admit, I'm unfamiliar with PyGame, so I'll leave that up to the reader.

**Alternatively**, you could compact this down quite a bit by making the direction of the form `pac.direction = (xSpeed, ySpeed)`. Then your code compacts to (without bounds checking which can be done before the lines):

```
pac.x += pac.direction[0]  # Could be pac.direction.x if you use an object instead of a tuple
pac.y += pac.direction[1]  # Same as above with pac.direction.y
left = pac.direction[0] > 0  # I'm unsure why you're doing left and right separately, so I'll just put left
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OR statement to check if Pac Man has already been given a direction:

`if (keys[pygame.K_UP] or pac.direction == "UP") and (pac.y - pac.radius) > 0:`

Repeat for each if statement per direction.

This is assuming that no other code is changing the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a variable to store the most recent direction

```
while True:
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and (pac.y - pac.radius) > 0:
        recent_direction = 'UP'
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and (pac.y + 2*(pac.radius) + pac.speed) < height:
        recent_direction = 'DOWN'
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and (pac.x - pac.radius) > 0:
        recent_direction = 'LEFT'
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and (pac.x + 2*pac.radius + pac.speed) < width:
        recent_direction = 'RIGHT'
while True:
    if recent_direction == 'UP':
        pac.y -= pac.speed
    elif recent_direction == 'DOWN':
        pac.y += pac.speed
    if recent_direction == 'LEFT':
        pac.x -= pac.speed
    if recent_direction == 'RIGHT':
        pac.x += pac.speed
```

Hopefully this works for you